# pyspark: Python worker failed to connect back(waiting for solution)

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

myconfig:spark-3.1.3-bin-hadoop2.7.7、hadoop-2.7.7、python-3.9、jdk11、scala2.12.8
IDE:pycharm
I run this demo, it runs succeesfully

```py
from pyspark import SparkContext
sc = SparkContext("local", "collect app")
words = sc.parallelize(
    ["scala",
     "java",
     "hadoop",
     "spark",
     "akka",
     "spark vs hadoop",
     "pyspark",
     "pyspark and spark"
     ])
coll = words.collect()
print("Elements in RDD -> %s" % coll)
```

but when I run this code demo, it fails

```py
from pyspark import SparkContext
sc = SparkContext("local", "collect app")
words = sc.parallelize(
    ["scala",
     "java",
     "hadoop",
     "spark",
     "akka",
     "spark vs hadoop",
     "pyspark",
     "pyspark and spark"
     ])

words_filter = words.filter(lambda x: 'spark' in x)
filtered = words_filter.collect()
print("Fitered RDD -> %s" % (filtered))
```

the error logs:

```
22/08/01 19:55:51 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker failed to connect back.
22/08/01 19:55:51 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\pythonProject\spark_learn\hello.py", line 14, in <module>
    filtered = words_filter.collect()
  File "E:\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pyspark\rdd.py", line 1197, in collect
    sock_info = self.ctx._jvm.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(self._jrdd.rdd())
  File "E:\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1321, in __call__
    return_value = get_return_value(
  File "E:\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\py4j\protocol.py", line 326, in get_return_value
    raise Py4JJavaError(
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
```

I have read some blogs before, and tried some solutions in the blog like add the environment variable `PYSPARK_PYTHON=python`,but it didn't work.

Comment: Have you added Python to both system env. variables and IDE env variables?

Comment: i add the spark.variables and py4j.var to IDE env and restart the computer,it works,thank you for your solution.